# How to fetch a remote file during build-time in Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby, netlify

I am using Gatsby to build a website, hosted on Netlify. The website shows the Video on Youtube playlist. In order to make a faster website, I would like to cache the videos in the youtube playlist locally.

So are there any memcache-like item on Netlify (or Gatsby)? Or should I use any alternative method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two steps:

1. Instead of storing the content in the project, store it in a CMS. [Here](https://github.com/datocms/gatsby-portfolio) is an example of using [DatoCMS](https://www.datocms.com/) to manage content and build a static webpage using Gatsby.
2. [`createRemoteFileNode`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/) would fetch the Youtube thumbnail into local cache. All I need to do is find the Youtube Thumbnail URL, then call the  `createRemoteFileNode` function. All is done within the `exports.createResolvers` in `gatsby-node.js`. Here is the code snippet:

```
exports.createResolvers = ({
  actions,
  cache,
  createNodeId,
  createResolvers,
  store,
  reporter,
}) => {
  const { createNode } = actions;
  const resolvers = {
    DatoCmsVideoItem: {
      featuredImg: {
        type: `File`,
        resolve: async (source, args, context, info) => {
          return createRemoteFileNode({
            url: source.videoId,
            createNode,
            createNodeId,
            reporter,
            cache,
            store,
          });
        },
      },
    },
  };
  createResolvers(resolvers);
};
```

This would fetch the file in node `source.videoId` and then store the file in node `source.featuredImg` for future use.